# Max and Moritz in alternating German dialects

Tags: dialect

> 1) Ach, was muss man oft von bösen
>   Kindern hören oder lesen!
>    2) Maggs und Moridds sin zwee solsche
>   Daachediebe, Fleeschl, Schdrolsche!
>    3) Schdatt dass se durch gscheide Lehra
>   Sich zom Guada dädat kehra –
>    4) Händs nur allpott drüber glacht
>   Und sich heimli luschtig gmacht.
>    5) Ja, zu jedm Blädsinn taugns
>   Wia zwoa Unschuidengal schaugns.
>    6) Leud veräbbeln, drangsalieren,
>   Große, klaane, und auch Diern
>    7) Appel, Beer und Plumm stibietsen –
>   Deit'n jo veel leeber mooken,
>    8) Brav ze sein, das reizt kee Aas,
>   Awer Frechsein, das macht Spaß!
>    9) Lern'n ooch noch? meene Jüte,
>   Kommt ja janischt inne Tüte!
>   10) Obar, Freinderl, frage nicht
>   Nach dem End von dera Gschicht.
>   11a) Dâs is gâr a schlechte sach.
>   Schmul un Scherkeh – weh un ach!
>   11b) Dâs *katoves* wâs séi treiben
>   Well ich mâhlen euch un schreiben.

This is Max and Moritz, each stanza written in a different German dialect. Which one is written in the Hesse-dialect? I'd be very pleased to find out the dialects of the other ones, too. (Except for the first one, which is written in simple German.)

EDIT: I hope you will indulge my addition of an eleventh quatrain. (marty)

Comment: The brilliant and reclusive Leah Robinson has translated Max and Moritz into Yiddish. Here is a short excerpt. I have altered the phonetic YIVO-institute transcription to make it more German-friendly. The words in italics are of Hebrew origin, except for tcheppen which is Slavic. >Oy, wie oft hört men bei leut (rhymes with fright) >Schlechts vun kind in unser zeit! >Ot vun asa pâar mir wéissen (rhymes with caisson) >Wâs séi Schmul un Schmerkeh héissen >‘Stâtts zu _musar_ sich zuhören (rhymes with sharin') >Un zu _mitzvos_ sich zu kehren >Fleggen séi _b’sod_ sein lachers, >Un derzu noch _khoyze

Comment: [Hier](http://www.hochzeitsplaza.de/hochzeits-forum/off-topic/off-topic/100826-dialektexpertinen-sind-gefragt/) geht's zur möglichen Lösung.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Maggs und Moridds sin zwee solsche
>   Daachediebe, Fleeschl, Schdrolsche!

<strike>Unsicher: Franken</strike>  Sächsisch lt. ladybug, danke dahin.

> Schdatt dass se durch gscheide Lehra
>   Sich zom Guada dädat kehra –

dädat klingt Pfälzisch

> Händs nur allpott drüber glacht
>   Und sich heimli luschtig gmacht.

<strike>luschtig würde ich nach Leibzig verorten. Oder doch Schwaben?</strike> lt. ladybug alemannisch, also im Raum Baden-Würtembergs.

> Ja, zu jedm Blädsinn taugns 
>   Wia zwoa Unschuidengal schaugns.

zwoa müßte boarisch sein.

> Leud veräbbeln, drangsalieren, 
>   Große, klaane, und auch Diern

Müßte Hessisch sein (Äbbelwoin := Apfelwein)

> Appel, Beer und Plumm stibietsen –
>   Deit'n jo veel leeber mooken,

Sehr norddeutsch/Küste, Tendenz Hamburg würde ich sagen, da mir von Lindenberg die Zeile im Ohr ist "An der Elbe, an der Elster an der Bill, kann a jeder mooken, wat er will".

> Brav ze sein, das reizt kee Aas,
>   Awer Frechsein, das macht Spaß!

Rheinisch, stimm ich zu. Obwohl ich da "Brav ze sin/Freschsin" schreiben würde, vielleicht auch 'dat' statt 'das'.

> Lern'n ooch noch? meene Jüte, 
>   Kommt ja janischt inne Tüte!

Berlinerisch

> Obar, Freinderl, frage nicht
>   Nach dem End von dera Gschicht.

Keine Ahnung. 'Obar' klingt ähnlich wie 'oba' Auch sehr Süddeutsch - womöglich aber Österreich?

Comment: Maggs und Moridds sin zwee solsche Daachediebe, Fleeschl, Schdrolsche! --> von wegen Franken, das ist astreines Sächsisch. :) Insbesondere die Fleeschl und Schtrolsche! // Händs nur allpott drüber glacht Und sich heimli luschtig gmacht. -> luschtig sagt man in Lepizig nicht, sondern eher Lustisch. Und heimli erst recht nicht. Das ist auf jeden Fall irgendein alemannischer Dialekt. Aber keine Ahnung welcher.

Comment: 2) könnte auch Fränkisch sein. Eigentlich würde ich im Hessischen statt *veräbbeln* eher *veräbble* vermutet haben. 7) ist Plattdeutsch.

Comment: 10 ist eine Mischung aus einem nicht näher bestimmbaren bairischen Dialekt und Hochdeutsch (teilweise vermutlich um den Reim zu erhalten). Wo genau man an "Oba" noch ein r anhängt weis ich nicht. Z.B. in Wien würde dieser Teil aber so lauten: »**Oba**, Freinderl, **frog ned** / **nochn** End **fu** dera Gschicht« (Unterschiede zur Version aus der Frage sind fett hervorgehoben)

Comment: 2) (also "Schdatt dass se durch gscheide Lehra Sich zom Guada dädat kehra –") würde ich ziemlich sicher als Schwäbisch einordnen.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my guess:

> 1) Ach, was muss man oft von bösen **Hochdeutsch**
>    2) Maggs und Moridds sin zwee solsche  **Sächsisch**
>    3) Schdatt dass se durch gscheide Lehra  **Schwäbisch**
>    4) Händs nur allpott drüber glacht  **Alemannisch**
>    5) Ja, zu jedm Blädsinn taugns  **Bairisch**
>    6) Leud veräbbeln, drangsalieren,  **Fränkisch**
>    7) Appel, Beer und Plumm stibietsen  **Plattdeutsch** (*angehaucht*)
>    8) Brav ze sein, das reizt kee Aas  **?** (der Rheinländer sagt *dat*)
>    9) Lern'n ooch noch? meene Jüte  **Berlinisch**
>   10) Obar, Freinderl, frage nicht  **?**

No clue what 8) (*Hessisch?*) or 10) (*südöstlich irgendwo?*) could be.

Comment: 2) und 6) could be Hessisch, too, even though in 6) I'd have expected *veräbble* instead of *veräbbeln*.

Comment: Bei 10 würde ich mutmaßen: Oberpfälzisch

Comment: 10 klingt mir nach Wien

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess the 6th to be Hessian, since it uses "veräbbeln".

The 9th is Ripuarian (Rheinisch).

Comment: 9 is not Ripuarian, it's Berlinerisch with 99% certainty. The Ripuarian variant would be: "Brav zo sin, dat reizt kin Aas,
Aewer Frechsin, dat maeht Spaß!" Although this would be a "light" Ripuarian variant, not a full-blown Koelsch.

Answer (score 2):

"Diern" doesen't sound very hessian to me, while "Leud" does, and http://www.hessenweb.de/?id=470 does list "veräbbeln".

Answer (score 1):

> 4) Schweizerdeutsch (Alemannisch), Umgebung Zürich
>   11) Yiddisch…

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, only 6 sounds Hessisch to me, but could be Pfälzisch too. Others suggested 2 might be too, and they have a point.